# Java Exception Handling Specificity

Tags: java, exception

I think it's easier to explain my question if I show my code first, so here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class a{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter either a, b, or c: ");
        try{
            String a = s.nextLine();
            if (!a.equalsIgnoreCase("a")&&!a.equalsIgnoreCase("b")&&!a.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            System.out.print("Entered letter: "+a);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException b){
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Only enter a, b, or c.");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a way to make three(3) different catch statements in order to specify in the error message that the user entered

1. another letter other than a, b, or c;
2. a non-letter character (number or symbol) OR
3. a blank space?

The thing that crossed my mind for the number error was NumberF

Comment: You can pass a message argument with details to `IllegalArgumentException()`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating three *separate* catch blocks you can modify your `catch` to :

```
try {
    String a = s.nextLine();
    if (!a.equalsIgnoreCase("a") && !a.equalsIgnoreCase("b") && !a.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(a);                 // observe this
    }
    System.out.print("Entered letter: " + a);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    String input = ex.getMessage();

    // check for spaces
    if (input.trim().length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Only black spaces entered");
    } 

    // check for numeric/special characters
    else if (input.matches("^[0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?]*$")) {
        System.out.println("User entered a non-letter character (number or symbol)");
    } 

    // check if it isn't a, b or c
    else if ((!input.trim().matches("a|b|c"))) {
        System.out.println("User entered value other than a, b or c");
    }
}
```

Observe here:

1. We are including the input entered by the user while throwing the
   exception
2. In the `catch` block we are fetching the value entered by the user
   and then based on some *if* conditions printing out the desired
   exceptions.

*You can tweak the conditions within the catch logic as per your convenience, I hope you get the idea behind it. Also, you can create a separate method for handling the exception and call it from the catch block.*

Comment: I see, this looks like a better way of going around my original problem. But is there a way to specify that the user entered a letter other than a, b, or c?

Comment: I meant a third distinction. A) a blank space, B) a letter but not a, b, or c; C) a non-letter character (numbers or symbols)

Comment: Yes. You can include a *regex* that matches numbers and symbols and include another `if` block. Maybe I can leave that as an exercise for you?

Comment: I have no idea what a regex is. Perhaps I should start there. *goes searching*

Comment: I've made you're life easy by including the answer for that question as well, do have a look! However, I do recommend you learning a bit of regex to fully understand the edit.

Comment: You can test the *regex* [here](https://regex101.com/r/4y5YNy/1). Please do consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it worked for you.